# Legend in absolute position behaves different in browsers

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I have a problem with different behavior in positioning `legend` in `fieldset` in **Chrome** and **IE11** and ( **Safari10** - though I'm not sure )
vs **Firefox** and **Safari 11**.

I'd like to see the same behaviour of `legend` like in Chrome, but when I add position absolute it does not help much.

```css
fieldset,
label,
input {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<fieldset style="height: 150px; left: 5px; top: 45px; width: 460px;">
    <legend>Original Legend</legend>
    <label style="left: 5px; top: 0px;">Label:</label>
    <input class="readonly" style="left: 80px; top: 0px; width: 180px;" readonly="" tabindex="-1" type="text">
</fieldset>
```

*Expected behavior is like in Chrome, IE11, Safari 10.*
 (`Legend`  is **not** taken into account in positioning elements inside `Fieldset`) 
[image]

*Unwanted behavior like in Safari 11, Firefox :

( (`Legend`  is taken into account in positioning elements inside `Fieldset`) )*
[image]

Comment: What is the expected behavior?

Comment: I'll add screenshots in a moment

Comment: So you _want_ both texts to overlap …?

Comment: @CBroe The aim is Legend is not taken into account in positioning elements inside Fieldset in Safari 11

Comment: So you are just trying to nail every single element into place with absolute positioning?

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: The reason I'm doing it that way is for fixing a bug. It is not a good idea to rewrite 10k lines of CSS written 10 years ago or more, because it's poor method.

Comment: I can no longer reproduce that issue, it seems like Chrome has now the same behavior as Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

i added position relative in the input,label and legend tags, and added an inline-block display to the input and label, so they be in the same line :

```
input{
   left: 80px;
   top: 0px;
   width: 180px;
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
}
label{
   left: 5px;
   top: 0px;
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

here's a jsfiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/yswjy9k3/2/

**Edit** : you can also remove all the positioning, you'll have the pretty same behavior, here's the jsfiddle without the positioning :

https://jsfiddle.net/yswjy9k3/4/

Comment: All I need to know is how to make Legend is not taken into account in positioning elements inside Fieldset.

Comment: you can remove the position : relative; in legend, it won't change anything, i think the problem was more in the position absolute in input and label, they were posiotionned the same way, that's why you had this effect ( i changed the jsfiddle)